# ListView OnClickItems change item color in Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

## I'm beginner of android studio. I want to know how to change the color if I click again the selected items on listview, Let say I click the first item it turns the background to color red and it will remain same to the other items but then my problem is when I click the red item again I want to change it to color blue. Below is my sample code it only remain the color when I click the item I have no idea to change it to color blue. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView list_view;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_views);
    list.add("Data 1");
    list.add("Data 2");
    list.add("Data 3");
    list.add("Data 4");
    list.add("Data 5");

    adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,list);
    list_view.setAdapter(adapter);

    list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int i, long l) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the currenly applied color in a variable.

```
int currentColor = Color.white; // make this a class variable
int color = currentColor == white ? Color.RED : Color.Blue;
v.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

PS this is a pseudo code just to explain the idea

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response and I appreciate it , but still it did not change the color at all i use this . https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEUgC.png

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to achieve this, this simplest one is you can check you background color in if condition before apply red color

```
list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int i, long l) {
        if (R.color.blue === ((ColorDrawable) v.getBackground()).getColor()) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }else{
           v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
         }

    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response but  where did you get value  R.id.blue? I know it comes from the activity_main  if Im not mistaken  but Im confused where to specify the id.blue thanks @treadkhuram

Comment: Color from resources you get through   getResources().getColor(R.color.color_id);

Comment: Yes, I already tried that , but the problem is I couldn't find a solution on how to convert this line ((ColorDrawable) v.getBackground()).getColor()) into int I guess . I already tried this please check the image and thanks again https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJZVm.png